# Como e qual a melhor forma de usar fontes com CSS?

Tags: css, font

Só é possível visualizar uma fonte em um site, se aquela fonte estiver instalada ou veio no sistema operacional ou *browser* do computador.

Estive pesquisando e encontrei alguns variados tipos de fontes que podem ser usadas em `CSS`.

- Com tantos tipos de famílias de fontes como: `serif`, `monospace` e outras, qual a melhor forma de usa-las?
- Como usar uma fonte externa, mas com garantia que o usuário a tenha em seu computador?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Decidi me aprofundar e cheguei a essa resposta:

Para definir que tipo de fonte usar em qualquer trecho de código `HTML`, através do `CSS`, devemos usar a propriedade `font-family` com o nome da fonte que deseja.
Assim, a sintaxe para se definir e usar uma fonte em `CSS` é:

```
font-family: "Nome da Fonte";
```

Pode-se construir todo o design de seu site baseado em uma fonte, e o seu leitor simplesmente não vai  ver a fonte porque ela não está instalada ou não veio no sistema operacional do seu computador.

*E agora, o que pode ser feito para isso não ocorrer?*

Uma das soluções para esse problema é dar uma lista de fontes como valor, para atributo o `"font-family"`, separadas por vírgula.
Existem dois tipos de nomes de família de fontes:

•   **Family-name** - O nome de uma fonte-família, como "times", "courier", "arial", etc.

•   **Generic-family** - O nome de uma família genérica, como "serif", "sans-serif", "cursive", "fantasia", "monospace".

- **Sintaxe de Family-name:**

  font-family: "Colibri", "Comic Sans";

O `CSS` vai tentar estilizar com a primeira fonte declarada, se ela existir no computador do leitor, ela será  exibida, e se caso ela não estiver presente, o estilo `CSS` tentará ser feito com a segunda fonte.
E por fim, se não tiver nenhuma das fonte no computador do usuário, o `browser` mostrará uma fonte padrão do sistema.

- **Sintaxe de generic-family:**

  font-family: "arial", "verdana", "sans-serif";

Comece com a fonte desejada e termine sempre com uma família genérica, para permitir que o navegador escolha uma fonte semelhante na família genérica, se nenhuma outra fonte estiver disponível.

Uma outra solução e muito usada é o: `@font-face`, você deve primeiro definir um nome para a fonte (por exemplo, minhafonte) e, em seguida, aponte para o arquivo de fonte.Veja:

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'minhafonte';
    src:url("../fonts/bubblegum-sans-regular.otf");
}
div {
    font-family:minhafonte;
}
```

E por fim podemos usar uma das formas mais simples e garantidas que são as fontes do [Google Web Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/), pois são fontes próprias para `web` e todas testadas e aprovadas pela plataforma google.

Para isso você deve especificar o caminho da fonte fornecido no `google fonts`, logo após a fonte está instalada e pronto para usar, temos que utilizar o nome específico que o site fornece para funcionar corretamente. Veja um exemplo:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web');
```

Ultilizando a fonte na `tag` desejada:

```
h1 {
    font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}
```

Além da segurança de usar fontes do Google Web Fonts, temos também a facilidade, sem precisar fazer download de nada, apenas copiando o caminho da fonte desejada que já está hospedada nos servidores do google e especificando o seu nome no seu arquivo CSS.

Referencias:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-family.asp

http://www.criarsites.me/como-utilizar-fontes-google-web-fonts/

https://tonyblack10.gitbooks.io/css/content/fonts/index.html

http://www.htmlprogressivo.net/2014/02/

Comment: Esta resposta também tem conteúdo integral de sites como [este](https://tonyblack10.gitbooks.io/css/content/fonts/index.html) ou [este](http://www.htmlprogressivo.net/2014/02/Fontes-CSS-Propriedade-font-family-Tutorial.html) sem que seja indicado a proveniência. Corrige isso por favor.

Comment: @Sergio Corrigido. Eu não sabia mto bem que funcionava assim, mas a partir de agora ficarei mais atenta quanto a isso. Fico grata, levo isso como dicas para melhorar futuras respostas.

Answer (score 4):

> Com tantos tipos de fontes como: serif, monospace e outras, que tipo
>   devo usar

O tipo da fonte é baseado em opinião ao usar serif, monospace ou outras.

> Como usar uma fonte original, diferente, mas garantir que o usuário a
>   tenha em seu computador

No CSS3 é possível configurar alguma fonte usando [@font-face](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face), e enviar junto na requisição, pois a página vai buscar a fonte no próprio projeto, dessa forma podendo usar qualquer uma.

Veja esse exemplo:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: minhaFonte;
    # A URL pode ser local também
    src: url("https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/2468/VeraSeBd.ttf"); 
}

body { font-family: "minhaFonte" }
```

Existem vários formatos para fontes, como o *ttf* ou [woff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Open_Font_Format), que podem ser baixadas e colocadas no projeto.

Comment: Editei minha pergunta pq achei que não estava transmitindo bem o que eu queria, dê uma Olhada. Aproveitei e pesquisei mais sobre a minha dúvida e formulei minha própria resposta.

Comment: upvoted @AlíciaTairini =]

Answer (score 3):

Uma forma que não foi cita é indexando a `fonte` direto no `<head>` do documento como uma `stylesheet`. O https://fonts.google.com tem uma variedade de `font-family` que pode ser usadas dessa forma por exemplo:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Serif+SC" rel="stylesheet">
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa forma é interessante porque caso em algum momento o usuário já tenha tido acesso ao ao link dessa fonte, mesmo em outro site, essa fonte vai ficar no `Cache` do Navegador, e não vai precisar ser "baixada" novamente.

**Execute para ver funcionando aqui mesmo!**

```css
h1 {
    font-family: 'Noto Serif SC', serif;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Serif+SC" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />

<h1>Minha fonte Custom</h1>
```

É interessante que esse link venha antes do link do seu `.css` para garantir que vai carregar de forma correta

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Serif+SC" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
```

E no seu `.css` basta vc usar o `font-family` onde quiser, dessa forma por exemplo:

```
h1 {
    font-family: 'Noto Serif SC', serif;
}
```

**OBS:** O inconveniente dessa técnica é que se o servidor do Google estiver lento e o usuário ainda não tiver a fonte em *cache* ele pode ter um *Flash of Unstyled Text (FOUT)* ou *Flash of Invisible Text (FOIT)* que é quando a fonte aparece transparente antes de carregar completamente, ou aparece uma fonte *default* do sistema e só depois que carregar a fonte externa o texto muda pra `font-family` correta. E se o server do Google cair ai vai carregar uma fonte `fallback` do sistema operacional do usuário mesmo.

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta. +1

Comment: @AliciaTairini eu que fico feliz em ter colaborado! 