# Como mudar a font-family de uma só div com ficheiro .tff?

Tags: html, css, font

Eu gostaria de mudar a `font-family` de uma `div` em particular para um font que não consigo encontrar o código, mas encontrei um ficheiro `font`. Como posso eu adicionar esse font? Será que existe um código para ele?

Neste [link](http://www.1001fonts.com/biedermeier-kursiv-font.html) encontrei o `font` que desejo.

Comment: Relacionado: [Que tipo de fonte usar em CSS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/191805/que-tipo-de-fonte-usar-em-css/192591#192591)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após baixar a font, vai vim uns arquivos com extensão .ttf, .otf entre outros. Adiciona esses arquivos na pasta do projeto, geralmente eu colo em public/fonts.

Para adicionar e usar a fonte no código utiliza-se `@font-face`, isso é conhecido com importar fonte:

```
@font-face {
     font-family: "NomeDaFonte;
     src: url("arquivo-fote.otf");
}
```

Na tag `font-family` você coloca o nome que irá utilizar.
Na segunda tag `src` você coloca o local onde se encontra os arquivos baixados.

Agora para adicionar em uma `div` especifica:

```
.minha-div{
     font-family: "NomeDaFonte";
}
```