# Como colocar uma fonte usando uma classe?

Tags: html, css

eu consigo colocar a fonte no site tudo tals.(como eu deixei) imagem abaixo de como eu deixei....(como eu deixei o código)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### e abaixo esta o arquivo css

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### resultado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### *só que eu quero deixa uma classe em vez do "h2" EXEMPLO*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### css

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

COMO EU FAÇO PRA CONSEGUIR O MESMO ?

agradeço desde já ajuda de todos !

Comment: Por favor, não coloque os códigos como imagem, isso impossibilita de copiarmos para reproduzir o problema. O site possui suporte a código fonte, basta fazer o [tour] para aprender mais.

Comment: Dê uma olhada nessa pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/191805/como-e-qual-a-melhor-forma-de-usar-fontes-com-css/192591#192591 . Pode te ajudar.

Answer (score 2):

Amigo simplesmente faltou um ponto `.` no nome da sua classe...

Todo o nome de classe deve começar com um `.` tipo `.rodape` e ai vc coloca os estilos. E no HTML seu elemento ficara com `class="rodape"`

Ex:

```css
.rodape {
 font-family: 'Margarine', cursive;
 font-size: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Margarine" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="rodape">
  Odonto
</div>
```

Recomendo que leia essa documentação da Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/Seletores_CSS

---

**Dica:**  Se vc já está indexando a fonte no `head` do seu site pelo `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bangers|Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">` então não existe motivo para vc usar o `@font-face` no CSS da forma que vc fez... Tente optar por uma ou outra abordagem, a não ser que vc queira fazer um *fallback* de fonte, que pelo que vi não é a sua intensão.

Da forma que vc fez o usuário está baixando a Font duas vezes, uma pelo link no `head` e outra diretamente do seu servidor `../fonte/etc`. Não faça isso é uma péssima prática.

Comment: sim pois recorri de varias maneira não tava obtendo sucesso, só consegui deixando na pasta.... estou com bastante dificuldade de colocar a fonte diretamente de algum link (preferência da google fonts)  .... como eu faço ?

Comment: Seu font-family está escrito errado! Se vc vai só usar o link no head vc deve colocar no CSS assim: `font-family: 'Bangers', cursive;`

Comment: poderia me chamar no whats app 11 952744168 não estou conseguindo :/ é claro se poder tbm sem problemas eu tento me virar aqui

Comment: @caiquesey se está funcionando aqui tem que funcionar ai tb, basta vc ter calma e fazer as coisas do início, basta colocar a link da font no head direitinho, e no CSS vc coloca o font-family com o nome certo. Procure tutoriais de como usar o Google Font que vai te ajudar, mas tudo que vc precisa está ai na resposta.